Muticlass segmentation with missing labels for some classes
I have a training data where images contain cats, dogs or both.
Segmentation masks are provided.
But for the images which contain both animals- only one class is annotated and other is ignored. Some images have cat segmentation mask annotated and some images have dog segmentation mask annotated but not both.
I cannot exclude such images from training data.
How do I make a combined model for segmentation using this data?
I am worried that for an image where both animals are present - but only one class' segmentation mask is present - the ground truth segmentation masks will be wrong.
